# Camera controller dismiss is not working in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, delegates, vndocumentcameraviewcontroller

I trying to dismiss camera view after document scanned but it does not work. I tried to dismiss using **present** method, camera dismissed successfully but the image scanned is not printed. If i use removefromsuperview then camera view got struct or getting crash.

Here camera scan document code used inside framework and i have used framework in sample project.

Here is the framework code for scanner:

```
public class A8Scan: NSObject, VNDocumentCameraViewControllerDelegate {
public var imageCallBack: ((UIImage) -> Void)?
var textVal = [VNRecognizedTextObservation]()
var textRecognitionRequest = VNRecognizeTextRequest(completionHandler: nil)
private let textRecognitionWorkQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "MyVisionScannerQueue", qos: .userInitiated, attributes: [], autoreleaseFrequency: .workItem)
var imageNew: UIImage?
var statusImage: UIImageView?
private var clientView: UIViewController?
public init(_ viewController:UIViewController){
          self.clientView = viewController
   }

public func showScanner(){
    self.createTaskController()
       print("Called Build")
 }

private func createTaskController(){

    let scannerViewController = VNDocumentCameraViewController()
    scannerViewController.delegate = self
    self.clientView?.addChild(scannerViewController)
    self.clientView?.view.addSubview(scannerViewController.view)
    scannerViewController.didMove(toParent: clientView)
    self.clientView?.present(scannerViewController,animated:true,completion: nil)
 }

public func imageFromFile(result: @escaping (_ image: UIImage?) -> Void){

         //the image
     if imageNew != nil {
         result(imageNew)
         }
         else{
             //callback nil so the app does not pause infinitely if
             //the error != nil
         result(nil)
         }
 }

public func documentCameraViewController(_ controller: VNDocumentCameraViewController, didFinishWith scan: VNDocumentCameraScan) {
        guard scan.pageCount >= 1 else {
            controller.dismiss(animated: true)
            return
        }

        let originalImage = scan.imageOfPage(at: 0)
        let newImage = compressedImage(originalImage)
        imageNew = newImage
        print(";;;", newImage)
        imageCallBack?(newImage)
        print("new image::\(newImage.size)")
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    public func documentCameraViewController(_ controller: VNDocumentCameraViewController, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error)
        controller.dismiss(animated: true)
    }

    public func documentCameraViewControllerDidCancel(_ controller: VNDocumentCameraViewController) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true)
    }

    func compressedImage(_ originalImage: UIImage) -> UIImage {
        guard let imageData = originalImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1),

            let reloadedImage = UIImage(data: imageData) else {

                return originalImage
        }
        return reloadedImage
    }

 }//class


extension UIViewController {

class func loadFromNib<T: UIViewController>() -> T {
     return T(nibName: String(describing: self), bundle: nil)
}

}//extension
```

Here is the code sample project:

```
import A8Scanner

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var img: UIImageView!
var im : UIImage?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func btnAction(_ sender: Any) {
 //        A8Scan(self).showScanner()
    let vc = A8Scan(self)
    vc.showScanner()
}


override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let vc = A8Scan(self)
           vc.imageCallBack = { image in

               print("image", image)
           }
 }
}//class
```

How to dismiss camera view and send image scanned to sample project?

Any help much appreciated pls...

Comment: I am having the same issue. If you found a solution please add the answer. It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @K-2SO nope still facing same issue.

Comment: So I am in SwiftUI, I just passed the binding bool I use to trigger the presentation sheet down to the coordinator and I am able to dismiss the view now. In UIKit I guess you would pass in  the ViewController reference into createTaskController() and call dismiss instead of calling dismiss or pop on the controller pass in from the delegate method.